# Java Character Isolation String Manipulation

Tags: java, string

I need to use the built in string methods to eliminate all but the letter characters in a string, isolating them next to each other in a mashed up single run on word, then make them lower cased. I know about the toLowerCase() method, but I'm not really sure how to do the first part. I've searched things like "Manipulating strings in Java" leading to oracle documents and other help sources that I haven't been able to track down what I'm looking for. This is how it should look with a sample input and output:

```
Input: "Hi, My name is Luke."

Output: "himynameisluke"
```

Thanks in advance with optimism.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code and describe what works and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't implement the code for you, But will explain the steps.

Steps are here

- There is [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method in String.
- First [`replceall()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  your white spaces, special characters.
- Then [`toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `charAt()` method to find out empty space, then by using if statement you can control it to delete that empty space. As you have told, use `toLowerCase()` method to convert into lower case letters.